# pivot table type output in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having data like this.

```
date           br   num   type
01092016       602   15    sb
01092016       602   10    mc
02092016       603   20    sb 
02092016       604   12     mc
03092016       605   11    sb 
03092016       605   13    mc
```

I want output in the following format.

```
date             br                                      tot
                 602     603      604     605
             sb   mc   sb   mc   sb  mc   sb mc          sb    mc
01092016      15   10   0     0    0   0   0   0          15     10
02092016       0    0   20    0    0   12  0   0          20     12
03092016       0     0   0    0    0   0   11  13         11     13
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table type output can be achieved in Mysql like so

```
select   tdate,
            sum(case when br = 602 and type = 'sb' then num else 0 end) as sb602,
            sum(case when br = 602 and type = 'mc' then num else 0 end) as mc602,
            sum(case when br = 603 and type = 'sb' then num else 0 end) as sb603,
            sum(case when br = 603 and type = 'mc' then num else 0 end) as mc603,
            sum(case when br = 604 and type = 'sb' then num else 0 end) as sb604,
            sum(case when br = 604 and type = 'mc' then num else 0 end) as mc604,
            sum(case when br = 605 and type = 'sb' then num else 0 end) as sb605,
            sum(case when br = 606 and type = 'mc' then num else 0 end) as mc606,

            sum(case when type = 'sb' then num else 0 end) as sbtot,
            sum(case when type = 'mc' then num else 0 end) as mctot         
from t
group by tdate
```

but mysql isn't designed to pretty print - you should maybe devolve to a reporting tool - also if you have more than your example number of branches and types it might be better to devolve the whole report to a reporting tool.